# Android Widget/EditText for telephone number and email?

Tags: android

I need to capture a telephone number and email in an android activity. What is the best widget type to use for this? EditText?  I would also like to indicate visually that the entry box is for telephone without needing the extra TextView saying telephone number if possible.  Also what type of validation is best for this.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try using android:hint to avoid the extra TextView, and android:inputType for telephone numbers and email.

What kind of validation are you talking about? Min/Max length?

Answer (score 1):

To restrict the input to only allow a specific pattern and specific values, and to provide some auto-formatting, take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html